# What does the setting option mean entitled "allow multi-thread downloads" in Es file explorer?

Tags: download-manager, es-file-explorer

What does the setting option mean entitled "allow multi-thread downloads" in Es file explorer' under download manager settings?[image: Download Manager Settings]!

Answer (score 0):

It will divide your Download file into Multiple parts and Start Downloading those parts in parallel. After Downloading all the files it will merge all the downloading parts.

The Toggle is for changing the behavior to multi thread or Sequential Download.